# Chrome Dev Console: Square brackets [] on german keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-layout, console

I'm using Google Chrome 57 (beta) and since some time I experience issues with the dev console.

When trying to insert square brackets into the console, instead of inserting the character the console switches tabs.

- When entering <kbd>[</kbd> (AltGr + 8), the dev console switches to
  the tab on the left.
- When entering <kbd>]</kbd> (AltGr + 9), the dev console switches to the tab on the right.

This behaviour made the dev console totally useles for me. Everytime I want to insert something like `var x = []`, I need to copy & paste the brackets from somewhere else - or, in my case, use another browser instead.

Is this a known issue and are there any solutions for this? What is causing this problem?

Comment: `Ctrl + [` and `Ctrl + ]` are the shortcuts for `Go to the panel left/right`, `AltGr + 8` and `AltGr + 9` are the key combinations for `[` and `]` and `AltGr` is pretty much the same as `Ctrl + Alt`. So nothing to worry about, everything works as expected. Same behavior on final Chrome 57.

Comment: @Robert this is just plain wrong. Even if it was "expected" behaviour, it would still be even more expected that javascript code can be entered into the console on international keyboards. But it is definitely not expected behaviour because the Alt key is pressed which changes the shortcut. Try Ctrl + Alt + A on a text. This does not select all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also have this issue with a Danish keyboard. It's confusing AltGr with Ctrl and triggering the next tab / previous tab shortcuts.

There doesn't appear to be a way to change the shortcuts, but it looks like the issue has been fixed in development builds and will hit the next major version of the beta (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685993).

Comment: This issue is now fixed in Chrome 58.

Comment: I'm using Edgium 86 with a nordic keyboard and can go to next tab with Ctrl-Å but can't find how to go to the previous tab. Any clues?